# How to passe table/view entity as a parameter

Tags: c#-4.0, types, entity-framework-4, methods, parameters

consider the following code , this is a method in my BLL to extract data from my DAL which is an EF4 .edmx file

```
public ObservableCollection<Glass> ShowGlasses()
        ...

            var result = from d in glassContext.GLASSes

        ...
```

now I want to replace `glassContext.GLASSes` with a parameter so that I can access different tables/views with the same structure using this method, for example I may want to use `glassContext.GLASSes2` instead, how can I do this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this

```
public ObservableCollection<T> ShowGlasses<T>(ObjectQuery<T> source)
{
   ...

  var result = from d in source

   ...
}
```